# JSF @Schedule timer

Tags: java, jsf, schedule

I have a web app using JSF and Glassfish 4.1. My task is to perform a scheduled function that every day at 10:00 perform a search in my DB and then eventually send an email. I think that the best way to perform this is a `@Singleton` with `@Schedule` inside like this :

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class AppController {

@Inject
private IncarichiController incctr;

public AppController() {
}

@Schedule( hour = "10", minute = "0", persistent=false)   
private void Control(){
    //Devo controllare se la fine di un incarico si avvicina
    Calendar oggi=Calendar.getInstance();
    oggi.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 30); // AGGIUNGO 30 GIORNI ALLA DATA ODIERNA PER IL CONTROLLO
    incctr.findScadenze(oggi); // CERCO GLI INCARICHI CON SCADENZA OGGI+30gg

}
```

}

What do you think about this? There are other and more efficient way to achieve this task?
Thanks for your tips.

Comment: I would choose a singleton EJB for this kind of tasks instead (`@Startup` `@Singleton` and if database transactions are not needed, then `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED`)).

Comment: Thanks, i'll read something about that.

Comment: When I use a Singleton, can I call a SessionBean function, or I have to rewrite the function in this Singleton because the SessionBeans could  not be initialized ? @Tiny

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs in codereview.se.